# Error when compiling code NODE MCU ESP8266-12E module in Arduino ide

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, error

Here is my sketch:

```cpp
#include<ESP8266WiFi.h>

char* ssid = "xxxxxxxx";
char* pass = "xxxxxxx";

void setup() {
 WiFi.begin(ssid,pass);
 Serial.begin(9600);
 while(WiFi.status()!=WL_CONNECTED)
 {
  Serial.print(".");
  delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("IP Address: ");
  Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
}
```

Here is the error:

```cpp
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.5.2/tools/upload.py", line 25, in <module>
    esptool.main(fakeargs)   File "C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 2653, in main
    esp.connect(args.before)   File "C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 460, in connect
    last_error = self._connect_attempt(mode=mode, esp32r0_delay=False)   File "C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 440, in _connect_attempt
    self.sync()   File "C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 379, in sync
    timeout=SYNC_TIMEOUT)   File "C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 322, in command
    self.write(pkt)   File "C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 285, in write
    self._port.write(buf)   File "C:/Users/ASUS/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.5.2/tools/pyserial\serial\serialwin32.py", line 323, in write
    raise writeTimeoutError serial.serialutil.SerialTimeoutException: Write timeout the selected serial port
serial.serialutil.SerialTimeoutException: Write timeout  does not
exist or your board is not connected
```

Comment: does the code "verify"?

Comment: This looks more like an error while uploading than on compilation to me. Have you selected the correct board settings?

Answer (score 2):

The section

```
void loop() {
}
```

Is missing in the code, add it and recompile and.....